# Tomcat, Spring MVC, redirecting users to 'www' without using htaccess file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, url

I am trying to append www. to the domain but I can't find a solution. I found the results using .htaccess file but this solution works with Apache server but I am working with Tomcat. 
For eg.
When user types in: `abcdomain.com`  
then it should redirects to the  : `www.abcdomain.com` 
Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is not very clear what you are asking and what have you tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one thing that comes to mind would be a `Filter` processing the requests before they hit your app:

```
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {     
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(arg0 instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)arg0;
            String url = req.getRequestURL().toString()+"?"+req.getQueryString();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(http(s?)://)www\\.");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
            if(m.find()) {
                //www is present -> continue
                chain.doFilter(arg0, arg1);
            } else {
                StringBuilder wwwurl = new StringBuilder();
                if(url.toLowerCase().startsWith("http://")) {
                    wwwurl.append("http://www.").append(url.substring(7));
                } else if(url.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://")) {
                        wwwurl.append("https://www.").append(url.substring(8));
                }                   
                ((HttpServletResponse)arg1).sendRedirect(wwwurl.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jan, It worked prefect.  Just small corrections :
 1. null check for `req.getQueryString()`        2. typo in 'https' in else condition

Comment: May also want to change condition: if(m.find() || url.contains("localhost"))